# Writing a thread safe optimized Datastore class

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am trying to write a thread safe datastore class.
This class object is shared with between many threads in `Generator` and `Consumer`, where the class members can be set or get.

By calling `setDatastore()` the object is set for usage at different threads.

Below is my code,

```cpp
#ifndef IF_DATA_STORE_H
#define IF_DATA_STORE_H

#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <memory>

class DataType1{public:int value;};
class DataType2{public:int value;};

class DataStore
{
public:
    DataStore(): _member1(), _member2(){}
    ~DataStore(){}

    // for member1
    void setMember1(const DataType1& val)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(_mtx1); // no one can read/write!
        _member1 = val;
    }

    const DataType1& getMember1() const
    {
        std::shared_lock lock(_mtx1); // multiple threads can read!
        return _member1;
    }

    // for member2
    void setMember2(const DataType2& val)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(_mtx2); // no one can read/write!
        _member2 = val;
    }

    const DataType2& getMember2() const
    {
        std::shared_lock lock(_mtx2); // multiple threads can read!
        return _member2;
    }

private:
    mutable std::shared_mutex _mtx1;
    mutable std::shared_mutex _mtx2;
    DataType1 _member1;
    DataType2 _member2;
    // different other member!
};


// now see where data is generated/consumed!
class Generator
{
public:
    void start(){/* start thread!*/}
    void setDataStore(std::shared_ptr<DataStore> store)
    {
        _store = store;
    }

    void threadRoutine() //this is called from different thread and updating values
    {
        // some code...
        {
        _data.value = 10; // keep a local updated copy of data!
        _store->setMember1(_data);
        }
    }

    private:
    std::shared_ptr<DataStore> _store;
    DataType1 _data;
};

class Consumer
{
    public:
    void start(){/* start thread!*/}
    void setDataStore(std::shared_ptr<DataStore> store)
    {
        _store = store;
    }

    void threadRoutine() // running a check on datastore every 1sec
    {
        // some code...
        auto val = _store->getMember1();
        // do something..
    }

    private:
    std::shared_ptr<DataStore> _store;
};


// fianlly start all!
int main()
{
    // somewhere in main thread
    std::shared_ptr<DataStore> store;
    Consumer c; Generator g;
    c.setDataStore(store); c.start();
    g.setDataStore(store); g.start();
}
#endif
```

**Questions:**

- Is there any other way than creating multiple shared mutex for each member?
- In `Generator.threadRoutine()` if I keep a local copy of `DataType1` does this cause high memory issues (I see high cpu and memory) when this block called frequently, don't if this is the root cause of it.
- Any other better way suggested?

Comment: You have a data race in the two `getMemberX` methods: the lock is released after the function terminates, however you are returning a reference that can be read even after the lock is released.

Comment: the code is influenced by https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex. Do you mean I should remove the reference to return an object?

Comment: Doesn't matter how you do it, but returning any kind of access (reference or pointer, to name the most common ones) will circumvent the protection of the mutex.

Comment: BTW: It's unclear what you're really looking for. It also seems you have multiple questions, which is bad. Split them, research them separately and ask separate questions (if necessary). Make sure you create a [mcve] for each.